Deploying Django App onto Elastic Beanstalk (mysqlclient issue)
Having a bit of a mare trying to deploy my Django app to Elasticbeanstalk AWS
I'm getting issues related to the installation of mysql. See log files:
----------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-engine.log
----------------------------------------
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [24 lines of output]
      Trying pkg-config --exists mysqlclient
      Command 'pkg-config --exists mysqlclient' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      Trying pkg-config --exists mariadb
      Command 'pkg-config --exists mariadb' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      Trying pkg-config --exists libmariadb
      Command 'pkg-config --exists libmariadb' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
        File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 130, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-0u1shkl5/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-0u1shkl5/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-0u1shkl5/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 155, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 49, in get_config_posix
        File "<string>", line 28, in find_package_name
      Exception: Can not find valid pkg-config name.
      Specify MYSQLCLIENT_CFLAGS and MYSQLCLIENT_LDFLAGS env vars manually
      [end of output]

My Python pip requirements file is:
beautifulsoup4==4.12.3
bs4==0.0.2
Django==2.2
gunicorn==20.1.0
mysqlclient==2.2.4
numpy==1.24.4
pandas==2.0.3
python-dateutil==2.9.0.post0
pytz==2024.1
six==1.16.0
soupsieve==2.5
sqlparse==0.4.4
tzdata==2024.1
whitenoise==6.4.0

and I've also specified the SQL flags in an addition .config file in the .ebextensions folder (as well as in the AWS console itself)
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    MYSQLCLIENT_CFLAGS: "-I/usr/include/mysql"
    MYSQLCLIENT_LDFLAGS: "-L/usr/lib64/mysql"

as well as yum package installation files in another:
packages:  
  yum:
    python3-devel: []
    mariadb-devel.x86_64: []
    mariadb.x86_64: []
    gcc: []

Some guidance on how to move forward would be appreciated, as I've been stuck playing with different options for a while

Can you try adding a prebuild hook that sets the MYSQLCLIENT_CFLAGS and  MYSQLCLIENT_LDFLAGS  environment variables? Can you verify that the paths /usr/include/mysql and /usr/lib64/mysql exist in your instance?

I've verified the paths exist via ssh connection to my instance. However, when I tried printenv it seemed the environment variables were not set by the .config file nor via the console configuration.

Strangely, it also doesn't seem to make a difference even if it do eb setenv - the SQL environment variables are still empty on the instance.

I'm failing to reproduce the error.
What's the solution stack for your elasticbeanstalk environment?
